# Replace Spaces in a File Path for Sever Child Process

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to run a child process from my meteor server. The child process needs a path that is valid in the terminal. However my path has spaces in it, and I need to construct the path so that the terminal can get to it.

```
EX: REAL PATH : ~/Desktop/foo foo
```

However it needs to be

```
~/Desktop/foo\ foo
```

for the terminal's sake

I tried `var filePath = filePath.replace(/ /g,"\ ");` but it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash.

The statement `.replace(/ /g,"\ ");` is replacing all spaces with a space, changing nothing. The reason for this is that `"\ "` is actually interpreted as only a space. The backslash must be escaped.

Use the following:

```
filePath = filePath.replace(/ /g,"\\ ");
```